# Copying and Renaming an Element from one XML file to another XML file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I Want to add the data to the xml file from my asp.net GUI.So i have a textbox in GUI.

So if user enters "IL" then i want to add a section in this way

```
<Employee Location="IL">
    <Male Value="True" />
    <Name Value="xxx" />
</Employee>
```

**XML file:**

```
 <Emp>
  <Employee Location="NJ">
    <Male Value="True" />
    <Name Value="xxx" />
   </Employee>
  <Employee Location="NY">
    <Male Value="True" />
    <Name Value="xxx" />
   </Employee>
</Emp>
```

**Note:**

Every time i add a new section here the inner elements are constant i.e. the following values are always to be same.

```
<Male Value="True" />
<Name Value="xxx" />
```

I am looking for how can i achieve this using LINQ to XML?

Comment: really any linq to xml tutorial is going to show you how to add elements and save to an xml file.

Comment: Do some research on your own before posting :) Searching on google with Linq to Xml or Create Xml in c# will give you lots of insight.

Comment: @MarkW My question here is i needed a suggestion on how to copy the constant sections of the code.Whether i have to copy on the fly or save it to a different xml file ?

Comment: why did some one down vote here ?

Comment: 101 LINQ Samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746 XDocument Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since only variable part of node you're adding is `Location` attribute, you can very easily extract that process to a method, like the following one:

```
private XElement CreateEmployeeNode(string location)
{
    return new XElement("Employee",
        new XAttribute("Location", location),
        new XElement("Male", new XAttribute("Value", "True")),
        new XElement("Name", new XAttribute("Value", "xxx"))
    );
}
```

Now when you want to update your existing XML with new employee data, you do it this way:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString); // or .Load, depending how you get XML
var newEmployeeLocation = textBox.Text;
document.Element("Emp").Add(CreateEmployeeNode(newEmployeeLocation));
```

New employee node will be added to existing ones.

For more information on XML trees creation with LINQ to XML (as this is what we're dealing with here), check online guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx).